# open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: asp.net, gridview

The following code is for binding a grid:

```
protected void BindGrid()
{
    using (clsDt.sqlCnn)
    {
        clsDt.sqlCnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_CRUD_JWELORDERS", clsDt.sqlCnn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@operation", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20));
        cmd.Parameters["@operation"].Value = "Display";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        grdView.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        grdView.DataBind();
        clsDt.sqlCnn.Close();
    }
}
```

and following for binding the dropdown on the same page:

```
protected void ddparticular(DropDownList ddlParticular)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ddlParticular.DataSource = clsDt.getDataTable("SELECT COM_CMCD,COM_CMNM FROM COM_MST WHERE COM_CMCD = (SELECT COM_CMCD FROM COM_TYP WHERE COM_CTNM = 'Jewellery')");
    ddlParticular.DataTextField = "COM_CMNM";
    ddlParticular.DataValueField = "COM_CMCD";
    ddlParticular.DataBind();
}
```

but when running it shows:

**There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see straight off the bat is binding a grid view to a data reader, which I'm not sure would work (you have to invoke reader.Read() to get rows), it may just never actually read, and never close the connection since the reader isn't finished (I may be wrong about that).

Out of interest, try replacing this:

```
grdView.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
grdView.DataBind();
```

with:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(reader);
grdView.DataSource = dt;
grdView.DataBind();
```

I've had some fair issues with datareaders binding to grid views, this is the way I usually do it now.